# Iterate through GridLayout childs to hide ImageViews of 3x3 board

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to hide all the image views of the GridLayout 3x3 board. I have tried using a loop to iterate through all childs of the layout and imageView.setImageDrawable(null);

Note: the following code has been placed inside a playAgain(View view) button method.

```
public void playAgain(View view){

        Button playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButtonID);
        TextView winnerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerTextView);
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        winnerTextView.animate().translationYBy(-100);

        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

       for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){

           ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
           imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
       }
```

[after pressing the button the app shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xod4e.jpg)

Here is the logs from logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.rootcomp.bills.joincoin, PID: 10140
>           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to
>       android.widget.GridLayout
>               at com.rootcomp.bills.joincoin.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:99)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>       2018-10-18 01:48:21.514 1740-5247/system_process W/ActivityManager: 
>       Force finishing activity com.rootcomp.bills.joincoin/.MainActivity

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always write `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` This way you could even skip the cast to `ImageView`: `gridLayout.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: I think the problem is with the for loop i am using to iterate through all childs of the GridLayout. It works fine while i comment out loop lines and crash shows up while trying to use the loop.

just used  imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  still remains the same error sadly.

Comment: Then look for the crash log in Logcat. What does it say?

Comment: <code>
 for(int i=0; i<gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
           gridLayout.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
</code>

still doesn't work :(.

Comment: Ummm... that's not quite what I was asking. Do you use Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, I found the logs on logcat but can't comment here because characters are too long. (I am a new member here and looking for my first help.)

Comment: But you can edit your own question (there is a small button below the android tag)

Comment: I just managed to find out and Thanks for your valuable time. I have added logs there.

Comment: Ah, OK, you have a ClassCastException. Now please look at the imports in your Java file - what is the full name of the GridLayout?

Comment: And then compare this to the full name of the GridLayout in your layout xml file. It looks like they are different. You should use the same GridLayout everywhere, for example `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

Comment: 1. import android.media.Image;
2. import android.provider.ContactsContract;
3. import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
4. import android.os.Bundle;
5. import android.util.Log;
6. import android.view.View;
7. import android.widget.Button;
8. import android.widget.GridLayout;
9. import android.widget.ImageView;
10. import android.widget.TextView;
11. import android.widget.Toast;

about the full name of the GridLayout:
did you mean the ID of the GridLayout? 

if that is - "gridLayout"

Comment: The full name is in the xml file is: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are casting a wrong version of GridLayout.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout at com.rootcomp.bills.joincoin.MainActivity.playAgain(MainActivity.java:99)

Are you using support version in xml and you using non support version in code?

```
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
```

They are both called GridLayout, but from different lib.

Comment: now replaced "<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout" to "<GridLayout" and it Worked!